# Tomcat Jmx Inegration enabling on Datadog Agent

Tags: jvm, monitoring, jmx, datadog

I am trying to add Tomcat-JMX Integration to the Datadog Agent, in order to achieve Remote Monitoring .
I am following the docs https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/guide/autodiscovery-with-jmx/?tab=helm#autodiscovery-annotations

This is the Environment  I am using in my case.
I am trying to integrate JMX in one my Deployment, in AKS environment and I am using Helm to upgrade my environment.
as suggested in the documentation., I am adding the annotations in my deployment file in helm structure.
My agent is JMX enabled, and i can see in deployment logs.
I have configured a service for this deployment and its reflecting.

Issue I am facing :
I am trying to add my annotations, in the deployment file, after deployment, it should be able make the remote connection , but its showing  these logs in the agent.
while i check the Java process., even its not reflecting this JMX process , it seems JMX process is not at all created, in my case.,

JMXFetch

Information

```
runtime_version : 11.0.18
version : 0.47.8
```

```
  Initialized checks
 
    tomcat
      instance_name : tomcat-10.75.12.110-1099
      message : Unable to instantiate or initialize instance 10.75.12.110:1099. Is the target JMX Server or JVM running? Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.75.12.110; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)]
      metric_count : 0
      service_check_count : 0
      status : ERROR
      instance_name : tomcat-10.75.12.110-1099
      message : Unable to instantiate or initialize instance 10.75.12.110:1099. Is the target JMX Server or JVM running? Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.75.12.110; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)]
      metric_count : 0
      service_check_count : 0
      status : ERROR
  Failed checks
  
    no checks
```

https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/guide/autodiscovery-with-jmx/?tab=helm#available-jmx-integrations
i have followed the above page for my annotations.

Following are the annotations i am using in my case

```
    Annotations: 
     ad.datadoghq.com/{{ .Values.configmap.app.name }}-container.checks: >-
              {
                  "tomcat": {
                "init_config": {
                  "is_jmx": true,
                  "collect_default_metrics": true
                },
                  "instances": [{
                  "host": "%%host%%",
                  "port": "1099"
                  }]
                }
              }

-----------

    - name: POD_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.podIP
    - name: JAVA_OPTS
      value: >-
        -Xms256m -Xmx6144m
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
         -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
         -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
         -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
         -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
         -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099
         -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=tomcat.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

even i tried with adding -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=tomcat..svc.cluster.local , but no luck!

Even i tried by altering some of the unwanted annotations, I am not getting the expected result., ie., remote JMX connection.,

I would requet your help in this.,